# $ is not defined, Uncaught ReferenceError while using Select2 plugin with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use the Select2 plugin to add a search bar to my select box.

I get the following error when looking at the page console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Searching different questions here led me to believe this error happens because the jQuery javascript is not included or put before the script is called. But I still could not find a way to make it work. How can I fix this error and make the select2 plugin work?

Here is the application.js file :

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/tmpl
//= require select2
//= require tinymce
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

I've tried rearranging the order of select2 in the application.js file in many different ways with no success (I tried to make sure jQuery was loaded right before Select2).

Here is the index.html.haml file :

```
%select{:id => "test"}
    - @lamps.each do |lamp|
        %option{:value => "1"}= lamp.brand + ' ' + lamp.category + ' ' + lamp.lamptype + ' (' + lamp.cct.to_s + 'K)'

:javascript
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#test").select2(); });
```

Here is the application.html.haml file :

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title= t('.lspdd_light_spectral_power_dis')
    %meta{:name => "viewport", :content=>"width=device-width, user-scalable=no"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true, :defer => "defer"
    = javascript_include_tag "d3.min.js", :defer => "defer"
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

Additionnal information :

- Rails version : 4.0.3
- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Thank you!

Edit #1:

Adding the a screenshot of the information displayed by the network dev-tool.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhN9J.jpg

If I understand correctly the application-ea826f14bc5ea6f6976b187ce8d3008e.js file includes everything mentionned in the application.js file?

Comment: look in browser dev tools network to see what is actually loaded and when

Comment: @charlietfl I just added the network information

Comment: @kpblc My bad, totaly forgot the link

Comment: @WBeauchesne click test 295 and show us string with error. i'am almost sure what jquery is not loaded, or loaded after your plugin. also you can try to use "jQuery("#some_element")" instead of using alias $

Comment: @kpblc $(document).ready(function() { $("#test").select2(); }); is the string with the error (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined)

Comment: @WBeauchesne ok change this string for test. $(document).ready(function() {console.log( $("#test").html() ); }); and check the dev concole - if it show html of select, jquey is loaded fine. if it's not - problem with jquery

Comment: @kpblc I changed for your string in the index.html.haml file and got the same uncaught error BUT when I type your string directly in the console, it shows the html of the select without an error

Comment: @WBeauchesne now we sured what problem is not with Select2 plugin) problem with loading of jquery. try to add $(document).ready(function() { $("#test").select2(); }); directly inside application.js, after all of you required files. omg now i mentiond one detail inside you layout see my redacted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use `//= require_tree` if you already include all you scripts manualy. this can be the cause of errors. remove this string and try to reload page

**p.s**
i also think what you are using incorrect sintax

```
//= require_tree
```

correct version contain dot

```
//= require_tree .
```

**p.p.s.** 
not about your main question, but you are using old version of ruby. check the newer

**one more important thing** what i didn't mentiond before. you are using `defer="defer"` attribute for deffering main script loading. inline javascript what you type on page loaded BEFORE main scripts

Comment: I just removed it from the application.js, it didn't fix the jQuery error but i'll keep it this way if it is a better practice. As for my ruby version, i'm looking forward to change the ruby version soon!

Comment: @WBeauchesne ok, problem also can be with turbolinks. try to swithc them off, or add jquery turbolinks gem

Comment: Just turned them off and it had no effect.

Comment: the defer="defer" attribute fixed it! thank you very much