# Why do I receive an Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple show page that has this haml code at the top of the file:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('Come on work.....');
  });
```

When I load the page, I receive this error in the console `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

The problem seems to be similar to this question here ([Uncaught $ error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205226/is-not-defined-uncaught-referenceerror-while-using-select2-plugin-with-rails)).

My application.js looks like this:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery-ui
#= require underscore-min
#= require chosen.jquery.min
#= require app
#= require_tree .
#= require twitter/bootstrap
#= require d3.min
#= require highcharts/highstock
#= require highcharts/highcharts-more
#= require highcharts/solid-gauge
#= require tagcloud
#= require ace-element.min
#= require tipso.min

# Remove the following trigger when TurboLinks are re-enabled
  $(document).ready ->
    $(document).trigger 'page:change'
```

I could use some help as to how I can continue trouble shooting all my other javascript files are working fine so I'm not sure what the problem is.

UPDATE

I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly but I've already tried reordering the files in `application.js` to this:

```
#= require_tree .
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require jquery-ui
```

And I get a new error saying that `JQuery is not defined`. I thought by having this in application.js file the jquery would be present everywhere. What am I missing here. Do I need to include the actual files in my `show.html.haml` pages?

Comment: The jQuery include has to happen *before* the first reference to `$`

Comment: Pointy thanks for the speedy reply. What do you mean by 'before the first reference to `$`? Is that the `$` in my show file? I'm not following.

Comment: @DanRubio Question : 1. where you are putting reference of the "application.js"  2. it's better to provide you snip of the refference of jsfiddle or stacksnip code

Comment: If that JavaScript code you say is at "the top of the file" appears *before* the generated `<script>` tag that pulls in jQuery, you'll get that error. Script blocks are evaluated in the order they appear as soon as the browser gets them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Pointy said the jQuery file needs to be included before your application.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="application.js"></script>
```

Comment: happymacarts thanks for the answer. Can you take a look at my update. I don't understand what I need to do. Do I need the right order of loading in my `application.js` file or are you saying I need your answer in my `show.html.haml` or `application.js` page? I thought  the asset pipeline would handle this and load it everywhere.

Comment: I am not familiar with HAML But yes the jquery script needs be included in the rendered html before the applicaion.js

Comment: Well it worked, but then what's the point of this gem then? https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails. I guess for another time.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to include jQuery reference in your page

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ Mohit Arora Duplicate answer to mine ( I guess I have a faster trigger finger) but to give credit to @Pointy he made the comment before i actually answered